# Swift, Navigation bar should not be shown on the login screen

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have initialized Navigation controller from the root controller (viewController), and wrote down the code to hide it initially

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
```

But when i go to next screen and click on the back button , i can see my navigation bar on my Login screen.

Ideally we can't show the navigationbar on login screen, What should i do to avoid this?

Comment: Initially it is hiding? Where you wrote this method?

Comment: yes, I wrote it on  viewDidLoad : navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

Comment: You must have done something wrong, for me it is working.

Comment: me also its working....

Comment: It is working initially for me too..But when we click on the back from the next screen and come again on the login screen than it is not hiding...

Comment: Code Updated check it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login Screen ViewDidload write following line

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: Pefect!!! that works...thanks Memon...So anything comes from the navigation should be written in viewWillAppear?